# At enterprise level, is Apache Tomcat used standalone or with Apache server?

Tags: apache, tomcat

Which one of these two is most commonly used scenario? I want to use the same scenario in my learning process. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know about the rest of the industry, but where I work we have Apache HTTPD front-ending for Tomcat.

Any static content is directly provided by HTTPD for performance. Pain in the neck to separate every app out, but there is a noticeable payoff.

Also, HTTPD has some nice code for cookie handling, URL rewriting, clustering and so on.

Only if we determine that there's dynamic, database-bound data to show do we forward to Tomcat, which does an admirable job there.

Has been working well for us for almost a decade. Others too, I would wager.

Comment: This is how we do it at my company too.

Comment: +1 for a good answer.  However it should be pointed out that in the newer versions of Tomcat, the payoff for serving static content from HTTPD is negligible.  Unless you are developing a site handling a ton of traffic, its not worth the effort to separate it out.